# How to Insert copyright symbol in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I add symbols like copyright in bigquery ?

I am trying to insert copyright symbols in bigquery, How do I do that ?

Thanks
Thirumalai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING` function:

```
SELECT CODE_POINTS_TO_STRING([0169])
```